# MS LogParser from a remote computer?

Tags: iis, logparser

We have a couple of webservers. And have LogParser installed on them. I use remote desktop to log in on a server. Then i use "LogParser Studio" to work with reports and querys. The problem is that i can only run a query on 1 server at a time and that i have to be logged in to the actual server.

Isn´t there a tool or something that can let me send query's to multiple servers and receive the reports? Maybe a browser tool or something that let me work with a remote LogParser?

Comment: What type of log are you using? If are IIS logs you can access via SMB if you are looking for events in the eventviewer you can use \\servername\Application

Comment: Yes, IIS logs. SMB? (i´m not a server admin)

Comment: \\computer\Shared_Resource

Comment: Already solved it by writing my own webscript. Thanx POLLOX for the comments.